# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace a character in a string (`original`) with another string.
I am getting an error on running the debugger.
I dont understand what is wrong with the syntax.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HI there</title>
    <meta lang="english">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        Enter the original string<input id="original" value="" type="text"> <br> 
        Enter the replacing string<input id="replacing" value="" type="text"><br> 
        Enter the location to be replaced<input id="tobereplaced" value="" type="text"><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="replace()">Submit</button>
    <br> Here you go the replaced string is:

    <script>
        function replace() {
            var original = document.getElementById("original").value;
            var replacing = document.getElementById("replacing").value;
            var tobereplaced = document.getElementById("tobereplaced").value;
            var replaced = "";
            var originalLength = original.length;
            var tobereplacedLength = tobereplaced.length;
            var k = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < originalLength; i++) {
                replaced.charAt(k) = original.charAt(i)
                if (original.charAt(i) == replacing.charAt(0)) {
                    replaced = replaced + tobereplaced;
                    k = k + tobereplacedLength;
                    i++;
                }
                k++;
            }
            document.getElementById("replaced").innerHTML = replaced;

        }
    </script>
    <h1 id="replaced"></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `replaced` is an empty string. This is why you can't access it via `charAt()`.

Comment: yes got that. thank you @Sandrooco

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to change the character of an empty string at line no:28 [replaced.charAt(k) = original.charAt(i)] this is the issue.
Also there are some unwanted increment in the code. please find the corrected below

I have updated the code below with // comment the code and added correct code. its working

```
        // var k = 0; //Commented
        //  debugger; //Commented
        for (var i = 0; i < originalLength; i++) {

            if (original.charAt(i) == replacing.charAt(0)) {
                replaced = replaced + tobereplaced;
                // k = k + tobereplacedLength; //Commented
                // i++; //Commented
            } else{
            replaced = replaced + original.charAt(i);
            }
            // k++; //Commented
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: I have refined the code to work for repeating characters and updated above. Now its working perfectly. Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Yes sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simplistic approach to the problem. It takes advantage of the .split() & .join() functions rather than using a for loop.

```js
function replace() {
  // set original string
  var original = document.getElementById("original").value, // << use commas so you don't have to keep typing var
    // set replacing string
    replacing = document.getElementById("replacing").value,
    // initialize newval
    newValue,
    // set replace position - this could also be called index
    replacePosition = document.getElementById("tobereplaced").value; // << end variable declarations with semicolon

  // split original string into array of characters
  var splitOriginal = original.split("");
  // use replacePosition as index value of character to replace 
  // & replace that character with replacing value
  splitOriginal[replacePosition] = replacing;
  // join array to form new string value
  newValue = splitOriginal.join("");

  document.getElementById("replaced").innerHTML = newValue;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>HI there</title>
  <meta lang="english">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Enter the original string
    <input id="original" value="" type="text">
    <br>Enter the replacing string
    <input id="replacing" value="" type="text">
    <br>Enter the location to be replaced
    <input id="tobereplaced" value="" type="text">
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="replace()">Submit</button>
  <br>Here you go the replaced string is:


  <h1 id="replaced"></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes this works fine too. But I was trying to work on without using the built in functions. Anyway thanks bro.

Comment: @bharathkumarreddy Oh, my bad. I realize you did not have a jQuery tag in the post. jQuery is a powerful javascript library. If you haven't learned it yet I would recommend it!

Comment: Yes, I started learning web development recently. What technologies are mandatory in this?. Thanks.

Comment: @bharathkumarreddy That depends on your development environment. The simplest method would be to link to a hosted version of it - google hosts jQuery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` (place that link like so  `<body><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script>script which uses jquery</script></body>`). It is important to place the jQuery script before any other scripts which depend on jQuery.
-or-
You could download the library http://jquery.com/download/ and store it on your system.